# How to make null value into sql server from api vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am doing a project with API and I have a null value in API response. I tried to write code to write it into the database, how do I make it pass a null in integer when there is a null value in the API?

name in sql server table is integer
phonenumber in sql server table is string

I tried to convert it to string first and then convert it from string to integer.

API Response:

```
"Data":{
    "name": "N/A",
    "phonenumber" : "12345678"
}
```

Code:

```
Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd())
Dim listArray As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject.Item("List"))
Dim name As String = Replace(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonArray(j).SelectToken("Data.Name")), """", "")
Dim name As String = Replace(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonArray(j).SelectToken("Data.Name")), """", "")
Dim con as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnection").ConnectionString)
Dim sqlStr as String = "Insert Into tblPerson(Name, PhoneNumber) values(@name, @phonenumber)"
Dim cmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, con)
Using cmd
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", phonenumber)
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
End Using
```